# Variable for checkbox is undefined

Tags: php, laravel, variables, checkbox, undefined

Undefined variable: Categories (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\Third\resources\views\posts\edit.blade.php) http://commmanager.com/posts/7/edit
The problem seems like at the edit.blade.php but I have tried searching for the answer but still, I don't get any. Please help anyone?

**PostsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\POst;
use DB;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth' , ['except' => ['index','show']]);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //$posts = POst::all();
        //return POst::where('title', 'Post Two')->get();
        //$posts = DB::select('SELECT * FROM p_osts');
        //$posts POst::orderBy('title', 'asc')->take(1)->get();
        //$posts = POst::orderBy('title', 'asc')->get();
        $posts = POst::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->paginate(10);
        return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'Organizer' => 'required',
            'EventName' => 'required',
            'EventDate' => 'required|date|date_format:Y-m-d',
            'Description' => 'required',
            'EventLocation' => 'required',
            'Collaborator' => 'required',
            'Contact' => 'required',
            'RecruitmentDate' => 'required',
            'Categories' => 'required',
            'TotalCommittee' => 'required',

            'poster_image' => 'image|nullable|max:1999',
        ]);

        // Handle DatePicker


        // Handle File Upload
        if($request->hasFile('poster_image')){
            //Getfilename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('poster_image')->getCLientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('poster_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore  = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('poster_image')->storeAs('public/poster_images', $fileNameToStore);
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }

        // Create Post

        $post = new POst;
        $post->Organizer = $request->input('Organizer');
        $post->EventName = $request->input('EventName');
        $post->EventDate = $request->input('EventDate');
        $post->Description = $request->input('Description');
        $post->EventLocation = $request->input('EventLocation');
        $post->Collaborator = $request->input('Collaborator');
        $post->RecruitmentDate = $request->input('RecruitmentDate');
        $post->Categories = implode(", ", $request->get('Categories'));
        $post->TotalCommittee = $request->get('TotalCommittee');
        $post->Contact = $request->input('Contact');
        $post->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $post->poster_image = $fileNameToStore;
        $post->save();

        return redirect('/posts')->with('success','Post Created');

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $post = POst::find($id);
        return view('posts.show')-> with('post', $post);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $post = POst::find($id);

        //Check if post exists before deleting
        if (!isset($post)){
            return redirect('/posts')->with('error', 'No Post Found');
        }

        // Check for correct user
        if(auth()->user()->id !==$post->user_id){
            return redirect('/posts')->with('error', 'Unauthorized Page');
        }

        return view('posts.edit')->with('post', $post);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'Organizer' => 'required',
            'EventName' => 'required',
            'EventDate' => 'required|date|date_format:Y-m-d',
            'Description' => 'required',
            'EventLocation' => 'required',
            'Collaborator' => 'required',
            'Categories' => 'required',
            'RecruitmentDate' => 'required',
            'TotalCommittee' => 'required',

            'Contact' => 'required',
        ]);

        // Handle Categories


        // Handle File Upload
        if($request->hasFile('poster_image')){
            //Getfilename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('poster_image')->getCLientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('poster_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore  = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('poster_image')->storeAs('public/poster_images', $fileNameToStore);
        }

        // Create Post

        $post = POst::find($id);
        $post->Organizer = $request->input('Organizer');
        $post->EventName = $request->input('EventName');
        $post->EventDate = $request->input('EventDate');
        $post->Description = $request->input('Description');
        $post->EventLocation = $request->input('EventLocation');
        $post->Collaborator = $request->input('Collaborator');
        $post->RecruitmentDate = $request->input('RecruitmentDate');
        $post->Categories = explode(", ", $request->get('Categories'));
        $post->TotalCommittee = $request->get('TotalCommittee');

        $post->Contact = $request->input('Contact');
        $post->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        if($request->hasFile('poster_image')){
            $post->poster_image = $fileNameToStore;
        }
        $post->save();

        return redirect('/posts')->with('success','Post Updated');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $post = POst::find($id);

        //Check if post exists before deleting
        if (!isset($post)){
            return redirect('/posts')->with('error', 'No Post Found');
        }

        //Check for correct user
        if(auth()->user()->id !== $post->user_id){
            return redirect('/posts')->with('error', 'Unauthorized Page');
        }

        if($post->poster_image != 'noimage.jpg'){
            // Delete Image
            Storage::delete('public/poster_images/'.$post->poster_image);
        }

        $post->delete();
        return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success','Post Removed');

    }
}


-----------------------------------
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row my-2">
            <div class="col-lg-8 order-lg-2">          
            <h1>EDIT RECRUITMENT APPLICATION</h1>
            {!! Form::open(['action' => ['PostsController@update', $post->id], 'method' =>'POST', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('Organizer', 'Organizer')}}
                    {{Form::text('Organizer', $post->Organizer, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' =>'Organizer'])}}
                </div><hr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('EventName', 'EventName')}}
                    {{Form::text('EventName', $post->EventName, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' =>'EventName'])}}
                </div><hr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('EventDate', 'Event Date')}}
                    {{Form::date('EventDate', $post->EventDate, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                </div><hr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('Description', 'Description')}}
                    {{Form::textarea('Description', $post->Description, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' =>'Description', 'rows' => 5, 'cols' => 40])}}
                </div><hr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('EventLocation', 'EventLocation')}}
                    {{Form::text('EventLocation', $post->EventLocation, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' =>'EventLocation'])}}
                </div><hr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('Collaborator', 'Collaborator')}}
                    {{Form::textarea('Collaborator', $post->Collaborator, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' =>'Collaborator', 'rows' => 5, 'cols' => 40])}}
                </div><hr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Categories</label>
                    <div class="checkbox" rows="5", cols="40">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="Categories[]" value="Education" 
                                {{in_array("Education", $Categories) ? "checked": ""}}>Education
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="Categories[]" value="Animals and Nature"
                                {{in_array("Animals & Nature", $Categories) ? "checked": ""}}>Animals and Nature
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="Categories[]" value="Culture and Arts"
                                {{in_array("Culture and Arts", $Categories) ? "checked": ""}}>Culture and Arts
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="Categories[]" value="Community Service"
                                {{in_array("Community Service", $Categories) ? "checked": ""}}>Community Service
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox"> //The problem is here where the $Categories is undefined what does that mean?
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="Categories[]" value="Festival"
                                {{in_array("Festival", $Categories) ? "checked": ""}}>Festival
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="Categories[]" value="Health"
                                {{in_array("Health", $Categories) ? "checked": ""}}>Health
                            </label>
                        </div>
                </div><hr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('RecruitmentDate', 'Last Recruitment Date')}}
                    {{Form::date('RecruitmentDate', $post->RecruitmentDate, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                </div><hr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('TotalCommittee', 'Total Committees Needed')}}
                    {{Form::selectRange('number', 0, 1000)}}
                </div><hr>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('Contact', 'Contact')}}
                    {{Form::text('Contact', $post->Contact, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' =>'Contact'])}}
                </div><hr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::file('poster_image')}}
                </div> <hr>
                {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
                {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' =>'btn btn-primary'])}}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

Comment: you are using a variable `$Categories` in edit page but this is not defined in anywhere. and thus you are getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the variable $Categories without returning it to the blade

here in edit

```
public function edit($id)
{
    ....
    return view('posts.edit')->with('post', $post);
// you should define the variable then write
    return view('posts.edit',['post'=> $post,'Categories' => $Categories]);
}
```